# Knights and Knives Logical Proposition

Tags: logic

I have a question regarding Knights and Knaves and logical proposition. If I want to solve the puzzle and I assume I have two kinds of citizens: Knights, who always tell the truth, and knaves, who always tell lies. On the basis of utterances from some citizens, I must decide what kind they are.

There are three kinds of citizens: `a`, `b` and `c`, who are talking about themselves:

```
a says: ”All of us are knaves.”
b says: ”Exactly one of us is a knight.”
```

To solve the puzzle I should determine: What kinds of citizens are a, b and c? I should solve the puzzle by modelling the two utterances above using propositional logic, and I assume that I can use `p` to describe a knight and `¬p` to describe a knave. How would I go about doing that? Any hint for someone who hasn't done any noticeable discrete mathematics in college?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with programming?

Comment: No. Which exchange would you suggest posting it to?

Comment: I don't know if there's one specifically for logic. This kind of puzzle would be asked in Puzzling, but I don't know if they allow for this kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A and C are Knaves. B is a Knight.

- If A is a Knight, "All of us are knaves" is true. So, A would also be a Knave. This is a contradiction. Hence, **A is a Knave.**
- If B is a Knave, then "Exactly one of us is a knight." is false. Meaning that 2 or more are Knights. But neither A nor B is a Knight. How can possibly be 2 or more Knights (since C is the only one with a possibility of being a Knight). This is also a contradiction. So, **B is a Knight**.
- We just showed that B is a Knight. So, he himself is the only Knight he is talking about. So, **C is a Knave**.

Now, I don't think you can model this argument in the Propositional Logic. For one, notice the universal and existential quantifiers ("All" and "Exactly One") in the statements "All of us are knaves" and "Exactly one of us is a knight.". For another one, notice that A and B are talking about themselves. Modeling situations like this is one of the hardest problems in the history (not kidding!). Look at the following links for more info:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-reference

Answer (score 1):

you can create a [Truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table),
by first look at it i can say A must be knave, and B is a knight. because if A is a knight he can't say he's a knave(lie), also he can't be right about that all are knaves (can't say the truth) so B is a knight(if B Knave he can't say the truth that makes A a liar and he must be one) and then C is a Knave.